# Using npm to install nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I try install express-generator(or angular-cli) with npm but not successful. 
It is an error as below:

```
...
30 verbose stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.40.162:443
30 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
30 verbose stack     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
30 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
31 verbose cwd E:\nodejs\hello
32 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
33 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "express-generator"
34 error node v7.3.0
35 error npm  v3.10.10
36 error code ETIMEDOUT
37 error errno ETIMEDOUT
38 error syscall connect
39 error network connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.40.162:443
40 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
40 error network and is related to network connectivity.
40 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
40 error network
40 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
40 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
41 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Hmm...why would you expect to be able to use npm to install node.js?

Comment: If you are behind a firewall, then you may have to set proxy (.npmrc file)

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

Answer (score 0):

> If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the  'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'

If you are behind windows firewall, you will have to use proxy to connect to npm registry.

You can create proxy in two ways

- Use these commands:

  npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
- Create a .npmrc file in C:/`<path to current user>` and add the http and https proxy

  proxy=http://username:password@host:port https-proxy=http://username:password@host:port https_proxy=http://username:password@host:port